# Understanding tensor product over different rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I am trying to conceptually understand better the tensor product.

Supppose we have 2 $R$- modules $A$ and $B$, where $R$ is some ring different from the integers. What is the difference of having the tensor product $A \otimes_R B$ as compared to $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$?

Particularly, what is the difference of having a tensor product of a ring $R$ and a tensor product over a different ring $S$ (maybe the integers)?

Thanks for your help and let me know if I need to give more details in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take $R=\Bbb Z[i]=\{a+bi:a,b\in\Bbb Z\}$. Let's also take $A=B=R$,
a module over itself. In $A\otimes_R B$ we must have $(i\alpha)\otimes \beta
=\alpha\otimes (i\beta)$. But this does not occur in $A\otimes_{\Bbb Z} B$
in general. Here $i\otimes 1\ne1\otimes i$ in $A\otimes_{\Bbb Z} B$,
since $A\otimes_{\Bbb Z} B$ has a basis $1\otimes1$, $1\otimes i$, $i\otimes1$ and $i\otimes i$ over $\Bbb Z$. Inside $A\otimes_R B$ we do have $1\otimes i=i\otimes1$ though.